# MOS circuit for RC circuit power

Tags: filter, nmos, pmos

I am currently working on a circuit where we read the time it takes for a capacitor to charge depending on the load. I would like to know what is the purpose of the first stage with Q1 and Q2. I also have a problem with Q2. The transistor is always ON, even when Vin is 0V. [image]

Comment: Q1 & Q2 should both be off when the input is a logic "0" . When input = "1", Cap will charge up to 5V.  But there is not way to discharge cap and repeat the test, other than reset Vdd and wait for discharge. Next time define specs.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 and the 1K resistor are mainly there in case
\$Vdd > V_{in_{HI}}\$.

The PMOS, Q2, requires:

- \$Vgs \ge 0\$ to turn off
- \$Vgs  < 0 \$ to turn on

In other words, drive the gate LO to turn it on and drive it HI to turn it off.

But there are two problems if your try to drive Q2's gate directly with Vin while \$Vdd > V_{in_{HI}}\$:

- Vin cannot drive the gate gate high enough so \$Vgs = 0\$ so the PMOS turns off.
- Q2 has limits to how much |Vgs| can be applied before it blows the gate. So when Vin drives the gate low, it might exceed the maximum Vgs because \$Vg = 0V\$ and \$Vs = Vdd\$, so \$Vgs = 0V - Vdd\$.

The first problem can be fixed by tying the gate of Q2 to a pull-resistor so that if left floating, the gate is tied to Vdd so Vgs = 0V and Q2 turns off, and then driving it with an open-drain output. This is where Q1 comes in. It converts the push-pull Vin output to an open-drain output.

The second problem is to not exceed the maximum |Vgs| when you pull Q2's gate to LO to turn it on. It is most convenient to pull it to GND, but if pulling it to GND would fry it, then you have to limit the voltage somehow. You can use zeners, but in this case they use a resistive divider. However, **your 1K-100K divider resistors are sized inappropriately for this task.** It would be practically pulling it to GND.

If Vdd = \$V_{in_{HI}}\$ you could drive Q2's gate directly.

---

Also, it would be easier to swap the positions of your capacitor and your load. That way you don't need a differential amplifier anymore and could just use a ground referenced amp to measure the capacitor voltage.

Comment: Well I checked the circuit, the pmos and nmos were switched. oups

Comment: @nigiroux That makes sense. I couldn't see why your circuit was doing what you said it was doing from the schematic.